# How to change the url as Subfolder

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My URL is: `http://www.website.com/profile.php?username=xyz`

But I want to change into this: `http://www.website.com/xyz`

Will it be possible using `.htaccess`?

I have tried but it gives me:

> Internal Error.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d
RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: Can you show your rule (even if it is not working)

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d
RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?username=$1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: This code looks fine. Can you check your Apache error.log to see what is exact error when you get 500 (internal server error).

Comment: [Thu Sep 17 13:07:15.016904 2015] [core:alert] [pid 2944:tid 840] [client ::1:59761] D:/wamp/www/website/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters, referer: http://localhost/website/profile.php?username=xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

There shouldn't be a space between `!` and `-f` or `-d` in `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, it is working But with any of the url is now page is opening. http://www.website.com/xyz, http://www.website.com/123abc....i think this is how it can be accomplish ?

Comment: Yes that's right. It will route any thing like `http://www.website.com/foobar` to `http://www.website.com/profile.php?username=foobar` Only your code inside `profile.php` can figure out whether username is valid or not by probably querying database.

Comment: Yes it solved my query, you provided excellent help to me. thank you.